# Exception Handling in Swing/Spring application

Tags: java, spring, swing, exception

I've implemented exception handling in my Spring Web Applications using both AOP approach and @ControllerAdvice method untill now and had no issues with them.

Now, I'm implementing a standalone Swing desktop application using Spring Framework and also trying these to handle exceptions but I couldn't make it work.

To shorten the details, I made a simple project;

[image]

Launcher.java;

```
public class Launcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            ApplicationContext context = null;
            try {
                context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
                MainFrame mainFrame = (MainFrame) context.getBean("mainFrame");
                mainFrame.init();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (context != null)
                    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
            }

        }
    });
}

}
```

Config.java;

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("main")
public class Config {

@Bean(name = "mainFrame")
public MainFrame createMainFrame() {
    return new MainFrame();
}

}
```

GlobalControllerAdvice.java;

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalControllerAdvice {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
public void handleException(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("hey");
}
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

public MainFrame() {
    this.setSize(500, 500);
}

public void init() {
    setVisible(true);
    int[] a = null;
    System.out.println(a.length);
}

}
```

So here in my init() method, trying to print length of "null" array throws NullPointerException which I try to catch in my ControllerAdvice but it does not work.

Can someone please help me understand what I'm missing here? Or what could be a better way to handle my exceptions?

**EDIT:** When I run the Launcher, frame shows up and NPE is thrown;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.MainFrame.init(MainFrame.java:14)
    at main.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:19)
```

But the System.out.println("hey"); in my GlobalControllerAdvice method is not printed out, so I guess my class is not aware of the thrown exception.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Please describe clearly what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: have you tried: try-catch? you try to handle the NPE in your ControllerAdvice, but how are you linking your ControllerAdvice to the code throwing the NPE? usually, there is not a generic way to handle a NPE, and you'll want to handle each case in a specific way, so why are you even trying to do something like this?

Comment: @GhostCat "does not work" means, my application throws NPE but my ControllerAdvice does not get it.

Comment: @Stultuske Because I want to log every single exception occurs in my application and I don't really want to handle this all around my different classes.

Comment: But what do you mean: the frame doesnt show up, and the whole application crashes, and just prints the stack trace? Again: give a [mcve] that contains such details. Also update the question, instead of putting more infos into comments please!

Comment: @ozgen again: you never link your method to the advice. how do you expect it to be triggered?

Comment: @Stultuske Ok, this makes sense. Then how can I link my method to the advice?

Comment: Are you using Spring in your desktop application just for the exception handling? This feels quite unnatural as spring is mainly designed for server side (web-)applications.